# Passing unknown amount of parameters in Asp.Net from web form to class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings,

I am passing a form to a class in ASP.NET and was wondering is there anyway to pass the number of fields from the form to the class?

Currently I have

```
foo(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5) {};
```

wondering if I could just do

```
foo() { formData.split }
```

Obviously I could just make a data object and pass that to the class. Just wondering if there is already something in Asp.net that does this.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you could provide part of your actual code? it would help understanding more precisely what's your problem...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but what about

```
void foo (params object[] args){
}
```

where `params` is the keyword for "arbitrary number of arguments".

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if i understand you're question, but if you want to get the number of fields (i.e. private variables) of a class, you can use the **Reflection** class.

If you want to pass a variable amount of parameters to a function, you can use the params keyword (or __arglist, but forget this one)